# Setting top and bottom margin of p as 0 not working

Tags: html, css

I'd like to set the margin (top and bottom) of p as 0, but it's not working! Screenshot below. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
.conD .grid .text p {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="conD">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <p class="title">Companies
        <p>
          <p class="intro">Our portfolio is stacked with companies focused on impacting <br> the next generation consumer.
          </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <article>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/Feals.jpg);"></div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>nnana</p>
            <p>nana</p>
            <p>windy</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Provide working example. as there is possible to be line-height or padding that "looks like" margin

Comment: Could you please share more css ?

Comment: Can you close your `p` tag and check. This `p` tag is not closed `<p class="title"> Companies`

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get those letters to "touch" because the distance you're (propably) referring to belongs to the height of the font. So with different fonts, font-rendering, font-sizes and propably even depending on device dpi this height will be slightly different. so even margin-top: -.23434564352343em (or whatever) won't give you exact measurements. I'd to test whether

```
.conD .grid .text p+p {
margin-top: -.123em /* (or whatever suits you) */
}
```

or lowering the line-height

```
.conD .grid .text p {
line-height: .85 /* (or whatever suits you) */
}
```

That will be as good as it gets with CSS. To limit the height to the exact height of each letter you would need to use javascript.